Manhua where the main character has a physique that is hated by powerful sects
I'm looking for a manhua where the main character (MC) is the young master of a family. He has a physique and constitution such that, if one person in the family has this, the whole family will be destroyed. His father ignored him and even threw him in the forest until he died and his body was deformed. Later, an old man will come, and he will have the same physique as the MC.
Then the old man told the story about his physique and constitution, and the old man was actually the sect leader of a sect that had a physical appearance like his, but only he had what was left. He took the MC on as a disciple and the next leader, and he is gone to search for more people that have physiques like them.
I read this manhua around 2020, and I remember that it has 100+ chapters.

When did you read it?  How old do you think it is?

I forgot. Maybe around 2020… I remember this manhua has 100+ chapters.

Powerful sects hate him! Get a physique that destroys families and come back from the dead with this one weird trick!

This is Vengeance of the Heavenly Demon.

Surprise! Mu Tian Ran has been set up, his martial arts skills crippled at the hands of his own brother. Not only that, he's been rejected by his own family, who tortured him only to finally disown him and throw him out, all because he has the Bloodline of a Slave. At the lowest point of his life, a mysterious man arrives to mentor him and help him develop his own hidden talents. It turns out that his Bloodline, which was so repugnant to mankind, is actually a gift from the Heavens called the "Heavenly Demon Bloodline," making Mu Tian Ran an extremely rare child said to be favored by the gods themselves. As he grows stronger, Mu Tian Ran begins his journey to wreak vengeance on those who had shamed him in the past.


